# How to calculate percentage of each category and only selected items in Power BI using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am working on some education data. There are 4 categories and each of them have got a list of items. I have got the numbers. I have made a Matrix table with the Categories and Items in the Rows and the Numbers as Values. What I want to achieve 2 things

1. Show percentages for each of the items based on the category subtotal
2. "Not stated" and "Not applicable" in each category should not be included to calculate the percentages.

Can someone please show me how to create a new measure using DAX in Power BI to achieve this.

Please see the below example screenshot in Excel for detail. [Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuzY3.png)

Here is a Power BI file with the example data - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AubIV2PXG9p4gql0qImMTHvl4ZDAWg?e=2flwnP

I am new to Power BI and DAX. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these below steps-

Create this **Measure** first-

```
category_total = 

VAR current_row_category = MIN(Education[Category])

RETURN 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Education[Number]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(Education),
        Education[Category] = current_row_category
            && Education[Item] <> "Not stated"
            && Education[Item] <> "Not applicable"
    )
)
```

Now create the % calculation measure as below-

```
percentage = 
IF (
    MIN(Education[Item]) = "Not stated" || MIN(Education[Item]) = "Not applicable",
    BLANK(),
    (MIN(Education[Number])/[category_total])
)
```

Now add the above **Percentage** measure to Metrics value and the output will be as below-

[image]

Comment: Your DAX formulas worked like a charm. Thank you very much. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I know this was a long time ago, but can someone explain to me why this works? Specifically, it seems like the MIN function here is grabbing the value of each row, but how is that working within the context of the calculate and filter function? Is it because the calculate function iterates over each row?